# Outlook migration of email accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, windows-registry, office365, exchange

I need to migrate the configurations of email account (Exchange and Office365) from an Outlook client to another one. I cannot (and I wont) retrieve any information about credentials and server configurations. Could I accomplish such task with a PowerShell script?

Comment: How many accounts do you want to migrate?
And what do you mean by account configuration? Is it mailbox data or something else?

If it is mailbox data, as far as I know, directly configure the exchange account on another mailbox client to synchronize mail, contacts, calendar, tasks and other data. Do you have any concerns about your unwillingness to do so?

Comment: In reality it is only a single account of a customer who have changed a laptop. This customer is not the IT admin, so they have not any access to Exchange/o365 server configuration. On the fresh Outlook client of their new laptop I have tried to add the account but credentials doesn't work (but works when logging to OWA). An alternative solutions could be to backup the existing account configuration on the old laptop, and import it on the new one. This is the aim of my original request

Comment: Try looking through these steps: https://www.datarepairtools.com/blog/export-outlook-account-settings/ . Specifically, exporting the outlook profile/registry settings, and copying any local .pst files.

Comment: "I have tried to add the account but credentials doesn't work" Is the configuration failed? Or other errors? If possible, please provide more information for me to study, such as screenshots. (In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy, please remember to hide your personal information)

Comment: No any error, @Christy: simply in the dialog box username and password aren't accepted. Outlook simply returns me they are invalid (even though the same credentials work fine with OWA). Where can I found any log?

Answer (score -1):

As I know, you can [enable global and advanced logging for Microsoft Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-enable-global-and-advanced-logging-for-microsoft-outlook-15c74560-2aaa-befd-c256-7c8823b1aefa) and you need to contact MS support for more inspection and analysis.

According to your description, in order to further confirm whether the problem is only related to the Outlook client, please try to add your account on other email clients (such as Mail) and check whether the configuration is successful.

On the other hand, you can also try to configure other accounts in your organization on that laptop to check whether the configuration is successful, so as to check whether the issue is related to a special account. If any account in your organization cannot be successfully configured on that laptop, the issue may be related to some settings in your organization. Please try to contact your administrator for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Not useful answer. On customer client I cannot get admin privileges to check their organization settings, nor I cannot try other mail client, disagreeing customer policy

Comment: Due to many limitations, I'm afraid I still have to do research on logging in to your account from the outlook client. First, please update your version of outlook to the latest version. Second, please try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and add the account to check if there are any differences. If the issue still exists, please provide more information about the inability to log in with your account password.

Comment: How are you doing with this issue? Is there anything you would like to update? Thanks!

Comment: I have followed the above mentioned instructions to write a script to export/import a chunk of registry keys, but I have not tested such method yet

Comment: Well, when you have the test results, you can post back.